# Understanding results of CRC8 SAE J1850 (normal) vs. "Zero"

Tags: python, binary, xor, crc

I need a verification of CRC8-SAE-J1850 messages and therefore wrote a script, that reads logs and needs to calculate CRC8 (non ZERO) from there to match them with the CRC8 values in the log and then check which step in the tool chain caused the hassle.

Anyway, I spent some time looking into documentation, SO posts and other peoples sourcecode, but I want to stick with python for easier textprocessing and interfaces to my other tools.

I found some code on sourceforge [evansneath's Python CRC Implementation](https://gist.github.com/evansneath/4650991) which is nicely straight forward and wanted to give it a go, but I figured it does not work as expected (maybe I understood something completely wrong, but I am stuck here):

```py
def crc(msg, div, code='11111111'):
    """Cyclic Redundancy Check
        Generates an error detecting code based on an inputted message and divisor in the form of a polynomial representation.
        Arguments:
        msg: The input message of which to generate the output code.
        div: The divisor in polynomial form. For example, if the polynomial of x^3 + x + 1 is given, this should be represented as '1011' in the div argument.
        code: This is an option argument where a previously generated code may be passed in. This can be used to check validity. If the inputted code produces an outputted code of all zeros, then the message has        no errors.
    Returns:
        An error-detecting code generated by the message and the given divisor.
    """

    msg = msg + code
    msg = list (msg)
    div = list (div)

    for i in range (len (msg) - len (code)):
        if msg[i] == '1':
            for j in range (len (div)):
               msg[i+j] = str ((int (msg[i+j])+int (div[j]))%2)

    return ''.join (msg[-len (code):])

#Testing:
# Use a divisor that simulates: CRC8 SAE J1850 x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+x^0
div = '100011101'#0x1D with leading 1 as given by polynomial
msg = '10101001' # 0xA9, just for a Test

print('Input message:', hex(int(msg,2)))
print('Polynomial:', hex(int(div,2)))

o = '11111111'
z = '00000000'

code = crc(msg, div, o)

print('CRC8 code:', hex(int(code,2)))

# Test for output code of '00000000' respectively '11111111' proving that the function worked correctly
print('Success:', crc(msg, div, code) == o)
```

I checked the results using this generator:
[CRC Generator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) which seems to be the only one featuring CRC8 SAE J1850 ZERO and non-ZERO.

Now the fun part: for ZERO the above code works perfectly fine.

Unfortunately the CRC codes I get from the software I want to check are initialized and checked against 0xFF ('11111111') where both tools deliver completely different results.
So far I wasn't even able to find some off-by-one issue (which I would have rated the most likely case) or a mathematical link between the solution calculated by the script above and the one by the website. 
The website complies with the result from the software however the python part above doesn't.

Can anyone point me to a documentation I might have missed or is it another issue? 
I already checked for MSB/LSB issues when entering messages on the website and tried initializing with 0xFE as some other code suggested. But no success... Most examples however are zero based and there I have no issues.

**Edit**:

I checked the calculation and went through an example by hand as well as printing every single step and achieved the same. So mathematically it seems correct, but what is the SAE doing other than appending a line of '11111111' and then XOR-ing bitwise, then shifting until there is a leading one again, XOR-ing etc... and spitting out the remainder? It must be an issue of understanding on my side.

```
Test 1 ---------------------------
Input message: 0xa9
Polynome: 0x11d
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 1']
 /
['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1']
 =
current message: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1 ', '1', '1', '1']
shift 0 Bits
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
current message: ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1 ', '1', '1', '1']
shift 2 Bits
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
current message: ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1 ', '1', '1', '1']
shift 5 Bits
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
CRC8 code: 0xab

Reverse Calculation: Check
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']
 /
['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1']
 =
current message: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']
shift 0 Bits
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
current message: ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']
shift 2 Bits
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
1 XOR 1 = 0
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 1 = 0
current message: ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']
shift 5 Bits
1 XOR 1 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
0 XOR 0 = 0
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
1 XOR 0 = 1
0 XOR 1 = 1
CRC correct: True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

It is never mentioned that for the SAE J1850 the input is XORed with 0xFF. Even though the C-code Mark Adler provided states precisely that in `crc ^= 0xff;` however it didn't help me understand what my problem was.

It was not a bug, my code worked correctly but it was the premises I assumed.

This is why the C-Code did not help me solve the issue, because I never understood THIS was the problem in the first place.

The corrected code for SAE J1850 Calculation (with XORin 0xFF, XORout 0xFF, non reflected, non reversed, polynomial 0x1D) Bit-by-Bit is as follows.

Credits for the code remain with [evensneath on github](https://gist.github.com/evansneath/4650991), I merely changed the input.

```
def crc(msg, div, code='11111111'):
"""Cyclic Redundancy Check
Generates an error detecting code based on an inputted message
and divisor in the form of a polynomial representation.
Arguments:
    msg: The input message of which to generate the output code.
    div: The divisor in polynomial form. For example, if the polynomial
        of x^3 + x + 1 is given, this should be represented as '1011' in
        the div argument.
    code: This is an option argument where a previously generated code may
        be passed in. This can be used to check validity. If the inputted
        code produces an outputted code of all zeros, then the message has
        no errors.
Returns:
    An error-detecting code generated by the message and the given divisor.
"""
# Append the code to the message. If no code is given, default to '1111111'
# Uncomment every occurence of msg_XORIN if not CRC-8 SAE J1850 
msg_XORIN = [] # XOR the input before appending the code
msg_XORIN = [str((int(msg[i])+1) %2) for i in range(len(list(msg)))]
msg = msg_XORIN

div = list(div)
msg = list(msg) + list(code) # Convert msg and div into list form for easier handling

# Loop over every message bit (minus the appended code)
for i in range(len(msg)-len(code)):
    # If that messsage bit is not one, shift until it is.
    if msg[i] == '1':
        for j in range(len(div)):
            # Perform modulo 2 ( == XOR) on each index of the divisor
            msg[i+j] = str((int(msg[i+j])+int(div[j]))%2)

# Output the last error-checking code portion of the message generated

return ''.join(msg[-len(code):])
```

The testcases from the question can be carried over. call once to generate CRC, call again with msg + generated crc to verify.

Good source: http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.8

Comment: From your description "It is never mentioned that for the SAE J1850 the input is XORed with 0xFF", I don't think you're quite getting it yet. There is an "input" only if you are chaining a CRC calculation, i.e. computing the CRC a chunk at a time, where the input is the CRC of the previous chunks. If all you are doing is calculating the CRC of a message, then there is no input other than the message and the length. Then the specification provides what to initialize the register to (`init`) and what to exclusive-or the output with (`xorout`).

Comment: Once you understand that, then it is obvious why an _initial_ exclusive-or with `xorout` is required when chaining, in order to reconstruct the contents of the register from the last run.

Answer (score 1):

That CRC is normally defined with these parameters:

```
width=8 poly=0x1d init=0xff refin=false refout=false xorout=0xff check=0x4b name="CRC-8/SAE-J1850"
```

[crcgen](http://github.com/madler/crcany/) will take that and produce C code to compute the CRC. You can easily translate that to Python if you like. Here is the bit-wise routine in C from crcgen:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned crc8sae_j1850_bit(unsigned crc, unsigned char const *data, size_t len) {
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc ^= 0xff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1d : crc << 1;
    }
    crc &= 0xff;
    crc ^= 0xff;
    return crc;
}
```

The "ZERO" version as listed on the linked CRC calculator page has these parameters, simply changing the initial and xorout values to zero:

```
width=8 poly=0x1d init=0x00 refin=false refout=false xorout=0x00 check=0x37 name="CRC-8/SAE-J1850-ZERO"
```

Here is the bit-wise routine in C from crcgen for that one:

```
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned crc8sae_j1850_zero_bit(unsigned crc, unsigned char const *data, size_t len) {
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 0x80 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x1d : crc << 1;
    }
    crc &= 0xff;
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: In the website resource I provided you can chose CRC8 SAE J1850 ZERO or normal. Depending on the manufacturers I work with, both might apply.

Comment: I understood your point and i tried the tool, however you didn't really relate to my question. I don't want Zero, but I figured for whatever reason, the code above does spit out the same as the webresource for the Zero part, but does not return the same (as the webtool) if I initialize and finalize with FF (respectively "11111111") but I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I'm not going to attempt to debug the Python code posted in your question. I have provided ways to correctly calculate the CRCs. The code in the question uses a terrible long division of a long (potentially very long for real messages) string of ASCII 0's and 1's, which is not how any CRC is calculated in the real world.

Comment: I know it is cumbersome and tables were the preferred option, but the positionshifting and XOR work for minor strings and to try and learn.  Furthermore I never asked about debugging, I just posted it, to show the code I tried, as requested on SO. I used your tool, got myself some C code bbb, but it turns out not much different other than shifting bits and not list positions. But I will never learn what is the issue if I just use some other code. Are we not here to learn? Finally If I never find the issue i will do it again from scratch but still the curiousity remains.

Comment: I would have to read your Python code and find out what's wrong with it. That's called "debugging". I apologize, but I don't feel like doing that. Maybe someone else here will take the time to do that for you for free. If you would like to learn about CRCs, you should read [Ross William's CRC tutorial](http://www.zlib.net/crc_v3.txt).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I really appreciate your time and effort, and I do already know Ross Williams tutorial (it is also mentioned at many sources and also here on SO). I was merely wondering if when dealing with an initialization of 0xFF there was something that might have slipped me. Because above code WORKS FINE with 0x00 init. Had I not posted the code the first comment would have been: show us what you already tried.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "initialized and checked against 0xFF". It is possible that you are confused about what initialization is. The initial value of the shift register is the `init` value in the specification. The initial CRC that you would feed to a typical CRC function is the CRC of an empty string, which is `init ^ xorout`. That is not `init` unless `xorout` is zero.

Comment: Hi Mark, i referred to init, the way most resources do, just like `width=8 poly=0x1d init=0xff refin=false refout=false xorout=0xff check=0x4b name="CRC-8/SAE-J1850"` on http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/1-15.htm#crc.cat-bits.8 - which by the way links to one of your projects. I have still not been able to find a reason, why this method returns the same result for init, xorout = 0x00 but different for init, xorout = 0xFF as the website ...